# How old is Sheila Sazs supposed to be?

Tags: suits

In the US TV series *Suits*, the character Sheila Sazs gets pregnant in Season 8 (2018). How old is she supposed to be?

(Rachael Harris, the actress that plays her, was born 1968.)

Comment: You do realize the actress has recently been pregnant twice, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachael_Harris#Personal_life

Comment: @BCdotWEB: You do realize that you can click on Wikipedia's references and in this case discover that the reference is a [*Daily Mail* article](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-6169993/Lucifer-star-Rachael-Harris-50-welcomes-second-child-son-Otto-husband-Christian-Hebel.html) which states, "She did not reveal if she was pregnant, or using a surrogate." (Also, nowhere in the Wikipedia article does it state that she "has recently been pregnant twice".)

Comment: It is sometimes possible for a woman who is 50 years old or older to become pregnant and have a child.  In fact, an important European dynasty had a medieval ancestor born when his mother was allegedly 50 years old, but I don't know if she was that old.  furthermore, it is possible for an adult actor to portray an adult character much older or younger than theirself..